# Check is there are unsaved changes in a redux app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I'm looking for an example of how to check for changes in a react-redux application. The application will prompt the user about unsaved changes when attempting to navigate away from the current route.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this would involve something like this in your component:

```
onClickNavigationLink = () => {
  const { checkLocalState } = this.props;
  checkLocalState() // we have access cause of `connect`
    .then(res => {
      if (res.areChanges) {
        this.setState({ proptUserConfirmation: true })
      } else {
        this.onClickNavigationConfirmation();
      }
    })
}

onClickNavigationConfirmation = () => {
  const { push } = this.props;

  push('/nextURL');
}
```

and then your action would look like

```
function checkLocalState() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return API.checkLocalState(getState());
  }
}
```

This would require some server-side service that can diff local state and the redux state tree. I don't really recommend this general pattern to begin with, however. You should know in your local application state if the user has unsaved data.